# hp alm rest defect links not returned

Tags: c#, rest, alm

I am using the REST API in C# to retrieve test data from HP/ALM.  I can find the test runs and link them back to the test cases, but I am having difficulty getting the linked defects.

I can get the defects themselves via

```
http://<alm-url>/qcbin/rest/domains/<domain>/projects/<project>/defects?query={detected-in-rcyc[=<cycle id>]}
```

However, when I try to follow the links to the test runs:

```
.../defects/<defect-id>/defect-links
```

I don't get anything.  I have noticed that the GUI has two tabs for Linked Entities for Defects: "Defects", and "Others".  Is there another query to get the "other" links?  I don't see anything obvious in the entity list available in

```
.../customization/entities
```

I am working with HP/ALM 11.00.

Thanks.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and I'm using HP ALM 12.01. The api consistently returns 404 (resource not found) even when my defect has links to tests (seen through the UI)

Comment: have you found any answers to the above ?

Comment: Hi ! I got very nice thing to used for making Rest api call , have a look to this  https://github.com/webcompere/ALMRestClient

Answer (score 0):

I've just verified it on **ALM 11 Patch 19**.

What I did?

Created a defect - defect1.

Created a requirement - requirement1.

Created a test - test1.

Linked both requirement1 and test1 to defect1.

Then called this REST API:

http://{your_server:your_port}/qcbin/rest/domains/{your_domain}/projects/{your_project}/defects/{your_defect_id}/defect-links

got the response:

```
<defect-links>
<defect-link>
<comment/>
<creation-time>2016-08-09</creation-time>
<first-endpoint-id xsi:type="xs:int">1</first-endpoint-id>
<id xsi:type="xs:int">1</id>
<owner>sa</owner>
<second-endpoint-id xsi:type="xs:int">1</second-endpoint-id>
<second-endpoint-name>Test1</second-endpoint-name>
<second-endpoint-status>No Run</second-endpoint-status>
<second-endpoint-type>test</second-endpoint-type>
</defect-link>
<defect-link>
<comment/>
<creation-time>2016-08-09</creation-time>
<first-endpoint-id xsi:type="xs:int">1</first-endpoint-id>
<id xsi:type="xs:int">7</id>
<owner>sa</owner>
<second-endpoint-id xsi:type="xs:int">3</second-endpoint-id>
<second-endpoint-name>req1</second-endpoint-name>
<second-endpoint-status>Not Covered</second-endpoint-status>
<second-endpoint-type>requirement</second-endpoint-type>
</defect-link>
</defect-links>
```

It looks like the resource */defect-links* returns all type of links.
At least this result may be filtered by *second-endpoint-type* attribute.

Honestly say don't know how this API works on other ALM versions/patches.